# How do I connect to Ubuntu from Android?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, android

I have a network of 3 PC's in my house: two are desktop PC's that are hard-wired to the router, the other being a netbook that is wireless. I also have 3 Android tablets that are wireless. I want to use a tablet to connect to my Ubuntu PC to perform terminal commands (the other PC's are Windows-based, so they're irrelevant).

I have tried TeamViewer, PocketCloud, and Splashtop, but all of these require things to be installed on my local machine, and I would like to avoid that if at all possible. I have searched Google for SSH, but I am not quite adept enough to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Thank buddy ...
your procedure does works . I can connect my ubuntu from android device. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would `ssh` into the machine via it's local ip, like this. It's best to specify username as well. Then you will simply be prompted for a password.

```
ssh USERNAME@192.168.XXX
```

You can install `openssh-server` by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

You need an `SSH` client on the android device. So you can handle the protocols needed. Use `ifconfig` to find your local ip on the host computer.

```
ifconfig
```

You can find more information here:

- [Connecting to ssh - Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/ConnectingTo)
- [Open SSH installation guide - Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

On your 'Ubuntu PC' simply run the following command to install openssh-server:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then get your the IP of your 'Ubuntu PC' using the command that Alvar suggested:

```
ifconfig
```

Then on your tablet install an SSH client like this one:
[Juicessh](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh&hl=en) or this one [SSHDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid&hl=en) and login to your 'Ubuntu PC' using your username@ip.

Comment: Also see [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot&hl=en) SSH client for Android in Google Play.